# React Redux toollkit hide show modal

Tags: reactjs

i am new to using redux toolkit, wanted to ask how should i update my modal,inside my reducer, I've tried updating state.modal to be action.payload but it doesnt seem to work.

```
export const uiSlice = createSlice({
  name: "ui",
  initialState: {
    modal: {
      type: "",
    },
  },
  reducers: {
    showModal: (state, action) => {
      state.modal.type === action.payload
    },
    hideModal: (state) => {
      state.initialState;
    },
  },
});

const handleOpenModal = () => {
    dispatch(showModal(TESTMODAL));
};
```

Comment: Shouldn't `TESTMODEL` be in quotations so that its read as a string?

Answer (score 3):

If you are solely trying to toggle the modal to 'show' and 'hide', you can set your modal equal to a "boolean". Then, you can access the "initialState" in your reducer and set it to the opposite of the previous state (using '!').

```
export uiSlice = createSlice({
  name: "ui",
  initialState: {
    showUi: false,
  },
  reducers: {
    toggleUiShow: (state) => {
      state.showUi = !state.showUi;
    },
  },
});

export const {toggleUiShow} = uiSlice.actions;
export default cartSlice.reducer;
```

After you have created a store and exported your reducer functions- you can import the state, the dispatch function, as well as the action to the required components. To access the state you would also import the useSelector hook.

For example, in your function component:

```
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
//in your function component you can access the state with the useSelector hook

const showUI = useSelector((state)=>state.[your_pointer_from_store].showUi)
```

Now you have stored the state in a variable and can access the state in the required component body. To dispatch the function...

```
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { toggleUiShow} from 'your-js-file'
//in your function component you can update the state with the useDispatch hook
//
const dispatch = useDispatch()
//
const toggleHandler = ()=>{
   dispatch(toggleUiShow()) 
}
//pass the handler to the required function ie. onClick={toggleHandler}
```